# Octopress can't build with Code Block

Tags: jekyll, octopress, jekyll-extensions

I try to do something like this [Octopress code block](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/codeblock/)

But I can't make it work.

It always shows the following error. My machine is Windows 7.

```
$ rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
unchanged sass/screen.scss
Configuration from d:/MyProject/Git/octopress/_config.yml
Building site: source -> public
Liquid Exception: No such file or directory - python c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/mentos.py in 2013-01-06-octopress.markdo
wn
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:162:in
`spawn'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:162:in
`spawn'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:307:in
`popen4'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:41:i
n `start'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:203:
in `mentos'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:192:
in `highlight'
d:/MyProject/Git/octopress/plugins/pygments_code.rb:24:in `pygments'
d:/MyProject/Git/octopress/plugins/pygments_code.rb:14:in `highlight'
d:/MyProject/Git/octopress/plugins/code_block.rb:82:in `render'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:94:in `bloc
k in render_all'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:92:in `coll
ect'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:92:in `rend
er_all'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in `rend
er'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:124:in `
render'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.3.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:132:in `
render!'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:79:i
n `do_layout'
d:/MyProject/Git/octopress/plugins/post_filters.rb:167:in `do_layout'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/lib/jekyll/post.rb:195:in `ren
der'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:200:in `blo
ck in render'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:199:in `eac
h'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:199:in `ren
der'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `proc
ess'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/jekyll:264:in `<top (requi
red)>'
c:/Ruby193/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
c:/Ruby193/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
Build Failed
```

Without code block, it works fine. I have installed python 2.73 and 3.3 for windows but not luck.

I have tried pygments  0.3.7 and rubypython 0.6.3 as well. It doesn't work.

The funny thing is I google hours and hours,and I don't see anyone else have the same problem.

I must miss something very simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem. It turns out the PATH for Python wasn't set correctly.

It seems like Python doesn't set up the path automatically.

All I have to do is to add the path.

Comment: Thanks @maxisam. For me, it was caused because of the Python version incompatibility. Working combination: Jekyll 2.0 vs Ruby200 vs Python27. Culprit was the Python33 on the path.